# What (if anything) in Bitcoin is better than Ether in the application area of a payment system?

Tags: ether, bitcoin

I know of course that there is much more about Ethereum being a smart contract platform. I only refer to the characteristics of a cryptocurrency. If Ether is used for plain payment purposes similar to Bitcoin, it should be faster with no block size limitations. Let alone the speed (8-17s) is much better for payment purposes. I wonder if there is anything that's still better in Bitcoin, besides maybe the market capitalization that gives is robustness as a payment platform.

Why would Bitcoin remain a payment choice in the long run if it can't have the speed of most recent technologies? Is there any technological advantage Bitcoin still holds over Ether?

Answer (score 1):

As of today, the Bitcoin network is stronger than Ethereum because of the network effects of adoption (by users, merchants, exchanges, regulators, investors, entrepreneurs, the media, etc.).

Comment: I'm not sure if transaction costs can be a factor. It is expected that Bitcoin transaction fees will raise over time as a mining reward. It is unclear if Ether has any substantial transaction fees as a cryptocurrency.